# Python replace a line of file by indecie

Tags: python, replace

so basically I'm trying to figure out the best way to open a file and say replace the first line of the file with something else. Unfortunately, everything I come across uses .replace which only works if you know the string you want to replace. What is the best method if I know what line it appears on in the document and just want to replace that line with something else?

Code I have so far:

```
files = os.listdir(root.dirname)
    files = [s for s in files if ".xml" in s]
    print (files)
    for x in range(len(files)):
        with open(os.path.join(root.dirname,files[x]),"r+") as f:
            old = f.read()
            f.seek(0)
```

Comment: I suggest giving [this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) a read. Particularly pay attention to the readline method and then just do list manipulation ;)

Comment: Can you give some code to show your problem?

Comment: @daouzli, I updated my post with some code.

Comment: @Midnighter, that makes sense for how to get the line. Are you suggesting I take the results from the read line and then use it to do the replace or is there another write function your hinting at?

Comment: @daouzli Did you seriously delete all the code from the question **in an edit** even when you wanted OP to show code?

Comment: @awesomeyi I never deleted any code! But I reorganized the question. There was no code at that moment. I see that it was not taken into account.

Comment: @Kyle I wasn't suggesting anything more than has been posted in the answers by now. Good luck :)

Comment: @daouzli http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4814458

Comment: @awesomeyi ow! that's crazy! I don't understand. When I edited it there was no code! Perhaps it was added when I was editing it and then replaced it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I got it working using this:

```
def replace_in_file(filename, idx, new_line):
    f = open(filename, "r")
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    lines[idx] = new_line + "\n"
    f = open(filename, "w")
    for line in lines:
        write=line
        f.write(write)
    f.close()
files = os.listdir(root.dirname)
    files = [s for s in files if ".xml" in s]
    for x in range(len(files)):
        #with open(os.path.join(root.dirname,files[x]),"r+") as f:
            file = os.path.join(root.dirname,files[x])
            print("Fixing "+file)
            replace = '<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="'+root.filename+'"?>'
            replace_in_file(file, 0, replace)
            with open(os.path.join(root.dirname,files[x]),"r+") as f:
                old = f.read()
                f.close
            with open(os.path.join(root.dirname,files[x]),"w") as f:
                f.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n'+old)
                f.close
```

Answer (score 0):

You can:

```
# Open a file.
f = open("file.txt")
# Read all the lines.
lines = f.readlines()
# Replace the first.
lines[0] = "replacing text"
# Close.
f.close()
# Open for writting.
f = open("file.txt", "w")
# Write
for line in lines:
    f.write(line)
# Close
f.close()
```

Comment: Alright, this seems straight forward. I will give this a shot tomorrow, end of the day here. Thanks for the post.

Comment: I would use the `with open(<filename>) as f:` instead of just open.  Also if you want to remove the first line you would use `""` but if you want to replace the first line with a blank one you would use `"\n"`

Comment: would it be possible to do a read and write in one opening? I'm asking because when I write it as two seperate opens it complains that I'm trying to do an I/O operation on a closed file.

Answer (score 0):

To replace a particular line of a file that depends how you know which line.

If you know the number of the line:

```
def replace_in_file(filename, idx, new_line):
    f = open(filename, "r")
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    lines[idx] = new_line + "\n"
    f = open("file", "w")
    f.write("".join(lines))
    f.close()

replace_in_file("file", 0, "new line content")
```

You can use the function `replace_in_file` providing the file name `filename`, the index `idx` of the line to change and the new content `new_line` you want.

Comment: And, How is this different from my answer?

Comment: I was writing this in the same time than you but I posted it later. sorry!

Comment: @RaydelMiranda his actually replaces the line instead of removes it.  otherwise they're quite identical

Comment: nine minutes, must be a slow typer ;)

Comment: @KronoS mine don't remove the line it replace it, look again.

Comment: no I was editing it but before finishing I was away from keyboard ;)

Comment: @daouzli, I tried your function but unfortunately I can't get it to work properly. It wrote the changes to a file called file and wrote it to the wrong directory completely.

Comment: I figured out that I had to change "file" to filename. But for some- reason I'm getting this error for the lines[idx] = : list assignment index out of range